# FileWatcher fires change event after file deletion

Tags: c#

I'm using a FileWatcher to trigger processing of files as soon as they are added to a folder. After the file it is processed it is deleted.

My problem is that after the file is deleted I get another file change event which is so close to the deletion than in some cases checking for File.Exists it tells that the file still exists. But of course some milliseconds later when looking to process the file it does not really exists.
The FileWatcher is set to notify on 
    NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.Size | NotifyFilters.Attributes

Thanks,
florin

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the `Created` event instead of the `Changed` one?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a little search on SO, you'll find plenty of questions, where people like to check if they are able to access a file or if they have the rights needed.

The problem is, that even if you check it (like you do with `File.Exists()`) the situation can be changed when it comes to the real operation.

So just throw out the `File.Exists()` and put a `try catch` around your deletion operation.
If it fails, it's up to you to decide if you just drop it silently, inform the user, close your application, shutdown the pc, etc.

Comment: The problem is not how to delete a file, but the fact that I have a change event fired after I delete the file. So the watcher fires a delete and after it fires another change event, at which moment (the change event) the file seems to still exist....

Comment: @florin: But if you have a try catch around your delete operation and make a proper reaction (drop silently, message in a TextBox) it shouldn't be any problem, cause the application works as expected.

Comment: I try to reformulate:
1. I delete the file X
2. I get a delete event event for file X
3. I get a change event for file X and as the file still exists it is queued for processing.
4. Processing gets to the file X and the file does not exists. Now at this point I can ignore the not exiting file case. But I want to log a message in this case because FileWatcher might not behave correctly (get internal stack overflow) and I want to log somewhere that there was some kind of inconsistency in the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

usually filewatcher fires multiple times since the fileChange is a series of events. 
Here is a useful link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx 
Scroll to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Save to say, it's been a while since this was asked, but seeing as I asked myself, if the change event will indeed be triggered when a file is deleted I thought I might as well chip in an answer.

To prevent your OnChange event from following through, you can check the FileSystemEventArgs for the WatcherChangeType and simply return, on a deleted event.

```
private static void OnChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Deleted)
    {
        return;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Changed: {e.FullPath}");
}
```